# Problem accessing GPUs with tf-nightly 2.4

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

Recently, the Ubuntu18.04 server I work on has been upgraded to the TensorFlow version 2.4.0 from 2.0.0. It started problem with accessing the GPUs which was working perfectly before. I noticed there are two versions available right now by `pip list` on my jupyter notebook. I also tried `tf.test.gpu_device_name()`, which returned nothing. Previously I was using the following code to assign GPU for my code:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"   # see issue #152
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"
```

And see the list of all devices, I was using:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

After the upgrade, the code above returns only the CPU name, not the GPUs.

My questions are:

1. This problem can be related to the multiple versions installed on the server. In that case, can I select a particular version to run my code? Right now, I am seeing `tensorflow-gpu 2.3.0` and `tf-nightly 2.4.0`. I know uninstalling one can lead to the solution but I don't have the sudo access.
2. Do I need to use new code to assign GPU because of the version change?
3. Do I need to upgrade the whole code to make it compatible with TF2.4?
4. I also think, `tf-nightly-gpu` may solve the problem but I need to be 100% sure.

I am using python3. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve with multiple tensorflow to access gpu. You should use Anaconda. This will also avoid for you the sudo problem. Try to install cuda-tookits and install tf-nightly. You can check [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/) for earlier version as example. Therefore, I don't think you have to change anything in the code. Furthermore, from tf2.x gpu has been automatically goes with cpu version, then the tf-nightly-gpu will not be necessary